# Match data.table and matrix and compute new column

Tags: indexing, data.table, match

I have two data.tables "commuters" and "distance". Distance is a huge distance matrix with row and column indices. Commuters has a column "home" and "destination".

commuters (1646044 rows):

| home | destination |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

distance (1187 rows):

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 238.23 | 453 | 263 | 1 |
| 2 | 21.2 | 1 | 238.23 | 238.23 |
| 3 | 577.98 | 238.23 | 4362 | 2443.22 |
| 4 | 234.12 | 987.98 | 89.93 | 12.21 |

I would like to add a new column "distance" to df commuters. So, if the value in "home" matches with the row index of "distance" and "destination" matches with the column index of "distance", I want to add the corresponding value in the matrix to this new column "distance" in "commuters".  The problem is that "home" sometimes the same value multiple times (that is why there are more rows in commuters than in distance). R keeps giving me the error that the rows in "cpmmuters" do not match the rows in "distance". However, I would like to keep duplicates (as you can see in the following table: "1 | 4" appears twice).

desired output:

| home | destination | distance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 453 |
| 3 | 3 | 4362 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |

What I have tried:

```
commuters$distance <- distance[cbind(commuters$home, commuters$destination)]
```

I get this error:
i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error is because `distance` ***is not a matrix*** as you claim, it is a `data.table`. Make it a frame or a matrix and this problem goes away. For the record, in this case (and many others) it would have been much clearer had you provided your sample data using `dput(head(distance))`: the use of `dput` is *unambiguous* and includes class and attributes, whereas given the Stack interface and your claim of `matrix`, the problem is not reproducible. It's only when I played with other possible classes that I discovered the error you claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything fancy (no melting required): the base `[` accessor for matrices allows for a 2-column matrix to specify row/column indices. Your error, however, is because your "matrix" (as you call it) is really a `data.table`. If it were a frame or a matrix, it works:

```r
as.data.table(distance)[cbind(commuters$home, commuters$destination)]
# Error in `[.data.table`(as.data.table(distance), cbind(commuters$home,  : 
#   i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please report to data.table issue tracker if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.
as.data.frame(distance)[cbind(commuters$home, commuters$destination)]
# [1]    1  453 4362    1    1
as.matrix(distance)[cbind(commuters$home, commuters$destination)]
# [1]    1  453 4362    1    1
```

So if `commuters` really is a `data.table`, we can do

```r
commuters[, dist := as.matrix(distance)[cbind(home, destination)] ]
#     home destination  dist
#    <int>       <int> <num>
# 1:     2           2     1
# 2:     1           2   453
# 3:     3           3  4362
# 4:     1           4     1
# 5:     1           4     1
```

---

Data

```r
commuters <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(home = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), destination = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
# the matrix version of distance ...
# to reproduce the error, convert this to a data.frame or data.table
distance <- structure(c(238.23, 21.2, 577.98, 234.12, 453, 1, 238.23, 987.98, 263, 238.23, 4362, 89.93, 1, 238.23, 2443.22, 12.21), dim = c(4L, 4L), dimnames = list(NULL, c("1", "2", "3", "4")))
```

Comment: Thank your for the explanation! Unfortunately, I still get the following error: "supplied 1642074 items to be assigned to 1646044 items of column 'distance'. " What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Check for `0` values in your `commuters`, as R does not work with a `0` index. For example with the data I have, do `commuters[1,home:=0L]`, and then `as.matrix(distance)[cbind(commuters$home, commuters$destination)]` produces a vector of length 4 instead of length 5. Perhaps your distance indexing is 0-based instead of 1-based?

Comment: Also, to be clear, given that `commuters` has integer columns, it is row/column-indexing based on _position_, not based on any row/column names that `distance` might have. If you need to instead work on the _names_ of the dimensions (where perhaps your `distance` has a row/column named `0`), then you will need to convert your ints to strings before `cbind`ing them.

Comment: In fact, I do have 0 in the columns "home" and "destination". But if I want to change them for an index match, I need to change every value in these columns by +1. Can you tell me how I can do that? Thank you so, so much!

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking. Do you mean `as.matrix(distance)[cbind(1+commuters$home, 1+commuters$destination)]` or `as.matrix(distance)[1+cbind(commuters$home, commuters$destination)]`? Or do you mean something special for _just_ the rows that contain a `0`?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as a melt and merge.

Setup

```
dist<-data.table(home = 0:4, 
                 `1` = c(1, 238.23, 21.2, 577.98, 234.12), 
                 `2` = c(2, 453, 1, 238.23, 987.98), 
                 `3` = c(3, 263, 238.23,4362, 89.93), 
                 `4` = c(4, 1, 238.23, 2443.22, 12.21))

comm <- data.table(home=c(2,1,3,1,1), destination=c(2,2,3,4,4))
```

Lastly

```
merge(
  comm, 
  melt(dist, id.vars='home',
       value.name = 'distance', 
       variable.factor = FALSE, 
       variable.name='destination')[, 
          destination:=as.numeric(destination)], 
  by=c('destination', 'home')
)

   destination home distance
1:           2    1      453
2:           2    2        1
3:           3    3     4362
4:           4    1        1
5:           4    1        1
```